# Integrating paypal standatd payment gateway issue using twig template engine php

Tags: php, paypal, twig

Please can anyone tell me how to integrate standard paypal payment gateway in twig template engine(framework) using PHP.

Please help me. Right now i am in big trouble and even i am beginner.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest thing to get basic payments working on your site would be to use [PayPal Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/) buttons.  You can create them from within your PayPal account profile, and then it just gives you a snippet of HTML to copy/paste into your site where you'd like the button to show up.

Since you're using PHP, if you want to get a little more advanced with the payment integration you could go with [PayPal Express Checkout API's](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) instead of Standard.  The documentation can be a little bit daunting, however, with the use of my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) you can handle everything very easily with nothing more than the knowledge of working with PHP array data.